# Typescript - Check item with condition

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have a list of clients and each client has an ID, a Name and Items. In the items there is a price and discount.

What I want to know is the final amount that all the users spent but only on items that had a discount. So, all items with discount and then the price - discount.

Is there a way of doing it with ES5/ES6? Because I can do it with vanilla JS but is not very clean.

Here is the code:

```
 let clients: { id: number, name: string, items: { price: number, disc:
 number }[] }[];  

 clients = [  
        {id: 0,  
               name: 'John',  
               items: [{  
             price: 120,  
             disc: 30  
         },{  
             price: 200,  
             disc: 50   
         }]  
     },  
     {  
         id: 0,  
         name: 'Doe',  
         items: [{  
             price: 135,  
             disc: 0  
         }]  
     },  
     {  
         id: 0,  
         name: 'Matt',  
         items: [{  
             price: 150,  
             disc: 10  
         }]  
     },   ]
```

Answer (score 3):

If i understand the problem correctly, you want the sum for all items from all users that have a discount:

```
 let sum = clients
    .reduce<{ price: number, disc: number }[]>((s, x) => s.concat(x.items), []) // flatten the item arrays
    .filter(i=> i.disc > 0) // filter
    .reduce((s, i)=> s + (i.price - i.disc), 0) // sum
```

Or if you want the items by client:

```
 let sum = clients
    .map(c=> (
    {
        id: c.id,
        name: c.name,
        sumItems: c.items.filter(i=> i.disc > 0).reduce((s, x)=> s+ x.price - x.disc, 0)
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you want to calculate the total, but this will help you :

filter the items and calculate price with discount :

```
 let clientsWithFilteredItems = clients.map(c => ({ 
    id: c.id,
    name: c.name,
    items: c.items.filter(i => i.disc > 0).map(i => ({ 
            priceWithDiscount: i.price - i.disc
        })),
}));


let clientsWithTotalDiscountedPricePaid = clients.map(c => ({ 
    id: c.id,
    name: c.name,
    totalDiscountedPrice: c.items.filter(i => i.disc > 0).reduce((total, x) => total + x.price - x.disc, 0),
}));
```

executable snippet :

```js
   
 let clients = [  
        {id: 0,  
               name: 'John',  
               items: [{  
             price: 120,  
             disc: 30  
         },{  
             price: 200,  
             disc: 50   
         }]  
     },  
     {  
         id: 0,  
         name: 'Doe',  
         items: [{  
             price: 135,  
             disc: 0  
         }]  
     },  
     {  
         id: 0,  
         name: 'Matt',  
         items: [{  
             price: 150,  
             disc: 10  
         }]  
     },   ]
     
     let clientsWithFilteredItems = clients.map(c => ({ 
        id: c.id,
        name: c.name,
        items: c.items.filter(i => i.disc > 0).map(i => ({ 
                priceWithDiscount: i.price - i.disc
            })),
    }));

    
    let clientsWithTotalDiscountedPricePaid = clients.map(c => ({ 
        id: c.id,
        name: c.name,
        totalDiscountedPrice: c.items.filter(i => i.disc > 0).reduce((total, x) => total + x.price - x.disc, 0),
    }));

     console.log(clientsWithFilteredItems);
     
     console.log(clientsWithTotalDiscountedPricePaid);
```